# Why my ASP.NET MVC can not insert data to my database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a small website using ASP.NET MVC but it can not create new, edit or delete data from the database. The data only shows on the webpage but when i use `SELECT *` command in SQL the data is not shown.

**My connection string in webconfig:**

```
<add name="CodeFileDBContext"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  connectionString="Data Source=HOANG-PC\SQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=Ciaos;User Id=sa;Password=**********;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

**Model:**

```
namespace Ciao.Models
{
    public class CodeFile
    {
        [Key]
        public int ColdeFile_ID { get; set;}
        public string Website_Name { get; set;}
        public string Service_Name { get; set;}
        public DateTime Date_In { get; set;}
        public DateTime Date_Out { get; set;}
        public int Service_Status { get; set;}

    }
    public class CodeFileDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<CodeFile> tbl_CodeFile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace Ciao.Controllers
{
    public class CodeFileController : Controller
    {
        private CodeFileDBContext db = new CodeFileDBContext();

        //
        // GET: /CodeFile/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.tbl_CodeFile.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /CodeFile/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            CodeFile codefile = db.tbl_CodeFile.Find(id);
            if (codefile == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(codefile);
        }

        //
        // GET: /CodeFile/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /CodeFile/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(CodeFile codefile)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.tbl_CodeFile.Add(codefile);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(codefile);
        }

        //
        // GET: /CodeFile/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            CodeFile codefile = db.tbl_CodeFile.Find(id);

            if (codefile == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(codefile);
        }

        //
        // POST: /CodeFile/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(CodeFile codefile)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(codefile).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(codefile);
        }

        //
        // GET: /CodeFile/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            CodeFile codefile = db.tbl_CodeFile.Find(id);
            if (codefile == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(codefile);
        }

        //
        // POST: /CodeFile/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            CodeFile codefile = db.tbl_CodeFile.Find(id);
            db.tbl_CodeFile.Remove(codefile);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any data in Details page?

Answer (score 1):

Add constructor to your CodeFileDBContext  class:

For example like this:

```
public CodeFileDBContext() : base("Name=CodeFileDBContext")
{
    var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)this;
    var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
    objectContext.CommandTimeout = 30; // value in seconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DbContext base class accepts connectionstring name as parameter. Try passing the connection string name  through CodeFileDBContext

Comment: hi. i use it already in the connect string "name="CodeFileDBContext""

Comment: yep sorry I didn't notice that do you get any exception try posting if you have one.

Comment: I used the data eplorer to test the connection from my website to data base and it's work fine. I create new data and it's list on the website view but it's not update to data base when in use SQL management tool to see the data in my table data

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us more details, what is the exact error you get?
Another thing you should check is that each data member in the model has its column in that specific table. If their names do not exactly match use the 'Column' attribute.
For instance, if they do not match try:

```
[Column("Table_Id")] 
public int ID { get; set; }
```

If they all match, add the 'Table' attribute, it helped me many times before.

```
[Table("YourTableName")]
{
public class CodeFile....
}
```

Comment: I connect to wrong table in database cause is the problem.!